# How do I set Java JDBC Environment Variables?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am building a simple Java 8 app using Vanilla JDBC to connect to a postgres database.  In my `getConnection()` method within `ConnectionUtil.java` I save my connection credentials in the following variables:

```
        String url = System.getenv("DB_URL");
        String username = System.getenv("DB_USERNAME");
        String password = System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD");
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file is as follows:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  jdbc:
    build: .
    ports:
    - 7000:7000
    volumes:
    - ./logs/log.txt:/logs\log.txt
    environment:
    - DB_URL
    - DB_USERNAME
    - DB_PASSWORD
    container_name: jdbc
```

For additional context, here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Base image with jdk 8 and maven
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8 as builder

# Copy pom.xml and source-code
COPY pom.xml pom.xml
COPY src/ src/

# Build application
RUN mvn clean package

# As a separate stage, to save on resulting image size, discard everything from previous stages
FROM java:8 as runner
# Base image only needs JRE 8

# Expose port 7000 for our web-app
EXPOSE 7000

# Copy the jar file from previous stage
COPY --from=builder target/jdbc-demo-jar-with-dependencies.jar app.jar

# Run program
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "app.jar" ]
```

I am still learning Docker. My question is, where do I set the environment variables?

Comment: You can set values directly in the `docker-compose.yml` file (https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers) or use a separate `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

In your current docker-compose.yaml you declared the environment variables without initializing them, just give them values.

Like this:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  jdbc:
    build: .
    ports:
    - 7000:7000
    volumes:
    - ./logs/log.txt:/logs\log.txt
    environment:
    - DB_URL=https://db.address.com
    - DB_USERNAME=db_username
    - DB_PASSWORD=db_password
    container_name: jdbc
```

Comment: If I were to actually add the url, password, and username, wouldn't it be bad practice to push this to github since my creds would be exposed?  I assumed that these variables would exist somewhere else and that is what I'm asking about.

Comment: That is not clear from your question , you need a some service that the app will access and ask for the secrets, like hashicorp vault, or if you use build tool like github actions or gitllab ci you can save secret variables and inject them during the build process to the image if the image is stored in secure location, or to the container  .during the deployment process the same way.